# Vagrant starts but cannot connect until I do a 'force provision'

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox, vagrant, vagrantfile

I've got a Windows 7 machine setup with vagrant/virtualBox - each morning when I try to access my development site it always a 'Unable to connect' error message in my Firefox browser.

Even though I have booted the machine using the 'vagrant up' command for some reason it only seems to be accessible via the browser once I have done the 'vagrant provision' command. This is obviously annoying as it starts doing stuff from scratch.. eg installing my mysql database again.

Can anyone provide any light into this, and why it seems to fail to connect all the time - as this provision command is only a temporary fix as i'll need to amend the DB everytime which is only feasible in the short term.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might just be my own setup - but I noticed nginx was restarting so have to restart this each time